# Paypal iOS SDK and php

Tags: php, ios, paypal

How to process in server when payPalPaymentViewController:didCompletePayment completion in iOS paypal SDK. Please give me a sample php code to process completedPayment.confirmation details. I am not familiar with php. So please give me a guideline to process paypal request in php server. I googled a lost but i can't find any simple solution to process paypal iOS request in php

Answer (score 2):

You can find sample code (cURL) on how to verify a mobile payment [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/).  Once you validate that the payment is completed, you can find other RESTful sample calls [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/) to do the server side integration. You can select the appropriate programming language from the top of the page.